# Putting objects into boxes so that each box gets <=2 objects

Tags: co.combinatorics

We have $k$ different objects and $n$ different boxes. In how many ways can we put those objects into boxes so that each box gets 0, 1 or 2 objects? Each object has to be in a box.

This looks different than any of the standard combinatorial problems (like partitions etc). It's relatively easy to express this as a sum or to get some kind of recursive formula, but can we get a closed formula?

Comment: When asking a question like this, please compute some examples so that readers don't have to.  In this case, the sequence 1, 3, 9, 24, 54, 90, 90 for $n=3$ leads to http://oeis.org/A141765

Comment: The general case is http://oeis.org/A027907 , and the case $k=n$ is http://oeis.org/A002426 . No explicit closed formula is likely.

Comment: Brendan: I think you are mistaken; the OP asked for $k$ *different* objects, which I take to mean that they're distinguishable (note that he used exactly the same adjective for the boxes).  The sequence you quote assumes the objects are indistinguishable.  In that case the sequence in Barry Cipra's comment is certainly correct for the case $n=3$.

Comment: In fact, the case $k=n$ is http://oeis.org/A012244 .

Comment: @Steve: You are quite correct!

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ letters, so that $S_k\times S_n$ acts on the set of allowable placements in the obvious way.

For a placement with $A$ boxes having 2 balls, $B$ boxes having 1 ball and $C$ boxes having 0 balls, the order of the isotropy subgroup is easily seen to be 
$$A!B!C!2^A$$
so the orbit size is $n!k!$ divided by this expression.

Adding up the sizes of all the orbits, and accounting for the facts that $k=2A+B$ and $n=A+B+C$, we get the expression
$$\sum_{A=0}^{ceiling(k/2)}{n!k!\over A!(k-2A)!(n-k+A)!2^A}$$

Comment: From the OP's question: "It's relatively easy to express this as a sum [...], but can we get a closed formula?" 

Comment: TJ:  I'd have said that a finite sum of closed formulas is a closed formula --- but I suppose there's no definitive authority on what "closed formula" means.

Comment: TJ:  In fact, for fixed $k$, this reduces to a polynomial in $n$, which surely counts as a closed formula by anyone's standards.  

Comment: Steve: really?  What polynomial in n?  Since the sum grows exponentially in n, I think you mean to say something else. Gerhard "Have Polynomials Gotten Bigger Nowadays?" Paseman, 2013.03.11

Comment: Actually, I see where my thinking went astray.  For fixed k, the sum is bounded by p(n) and kp(n), where p(n) looks like some constant times n(n-1)...(n-k+1).  Never mind.  Gerhard "Apologies To Miss Emily Litella" Paseman, 2013.03.11